# The web page is ok with chorome, ie but mozilla again has problem

Tags: internet-explorer, encoding, mozilla

http://www.radikalgenc.com/bulten/ekim.htm this is a monthly newsletter. but it does not appear fine on mozilla, how can i fix this issue?

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.radikalgenc.com%2Fbulten%2Fekim.htm&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That page works if I explicitly set Encoding to Unicode, it looks like the tr-tr language is making the browser choose the wrong character set.

Edit:  I'd leave that line intact but add this line too:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"  content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: should I remove <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="tr-tr">  ?